# Error when executing SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I get the following error when I try and execute the code down below.  I have added the SQL string I pass as well.  What am I missing?

Error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TOURID =
>   25e5eed3-ea84-4c30-a660-2c880253da60'

My query,

```
DELETE * FROM TOURS WHERE TOURID = 25e5eed3-ea84-4c30-a660-2c880253da60;
```

My code,

```vb
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\_Development\Data\filename.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Dim DBConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Try
    DBConnection .Open()
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, DBConnection )
    Dim sqlAdapterTOURS As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    DBConnection .Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote when working with GUIDS like this:

```
DELETE * 
FROM TOURS 
WHERE TOURID = '25e5eed3-ea84-4c30-a660-2c880253da60';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your value should be surrounded by single quotes, like this:

```
DELETE * FROM TOURS WHERE TOURID = '25e5eed3-ea84-4c30-a660-2c880253da60';
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess: your GUID-type entry should be quoted, maybe?:

```
DELETE FROM TOURS WHERE TOURID = '25e5eed3-ea84-4c30-a660-2c880253da60'
```

Answer (score 1):

Access/Jet/ACE is not very GUID-friendly. Michael Kaplan wrote about this many years ago:

[Replication and GUIDs, the Good, the Bad, and the Ugly](http://trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033)

Depending on the context, you may need to use the VBA functions for working with GUIDs, i.e., StringFromGUID() and GUIDFromString(). I'm not sure exactly what you have to do in a SQL context, though. I do know you can't do a join between two GUID fields (you have to use implicit joins, i.e., using a WHERE clause instead).